# Pickling objects in an Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, pickle

I'm working on a project for work and am having an issue with pickling.

Here is a simplification of what I am trying to do:

```py
import pickle
from enum import Enum


class SiteInformation:
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

        # Would actually be doing a number of calcs with name and location and storing
        # as members.
        self.time_zone = 'UTC'


class Site(Enum):
    GN = SiteInformation('North Site', 'Location String1')
    GS = SiteInformation('South Site', 'Location String2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Pickling...')
    with open('site_test', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(Site.GN, f)
        pickle.dump(Site.GS, f)

    print('Unpickling...')
    with open('site_test', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    print(data)
```

When I run this, it fails during the unpickling:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seb/Development/Scheduler/scripts/pickle_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    data = pickle.load(f)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/Scheduler/lib/python3.10/enum.py", line 385, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/Scheduler/lib/python3.10/enum.py", line 710, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: <__main__.SiteInformation object at 0x7fd77007ed40> is not a valid Site
```

I assume that this has to do with the `__init__` call in `SiteInformation`, but I'm not quite sure how to fix this as I have little experience with pickling. I have tried implementing a `__repr__` method in `SiteInformation` but this did nothing more than make the `ValueError` more readable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.11 this will work as written.  In earlier Pythons you will need to add an `__eq__` (plus `__hash__` if you want `set()` and `dict()` support<sup>1</sup>)  to enable different instances of `SiteInformation` with the same values to compare equal:

```
class SiteInformation:
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

        # Would actually be doing a number of calcs with name and location and storing
        # as members.
        self.time_zone = 'UTC'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.location == other.location
```

---

Note: the `__eq__` shown is for example purposes only.  A "real" `__eq__` would look like:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.name == other.name and self.location == other.location
```

A `__hash__` could look like:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.name + self.location)
```

---

1: `__hash__` is needed for an object to be in a `set()`, or to be used as a key in a `dict()`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the useful information! I ended up removing `SiteInformation` and making `Site` an enum with more values and an `__init__` method, which seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this has fixed the problem and made the code base considerably cleaner (based off the `Planet` example in the `Enum` Python docs):

```py
class Site(Enum):
    GN = ('North Site', 'Location String1')
    GS = ('South Site', 'Location String2')
    
    def __init__(self, site_name: str, location: str):
        self.site_name = site_name
        self.location = location
        self.time_zone = 'UTC'
        # Insert other member calculations here
```